# Вывести вес в карточку товара

Tags: opencart

Приветствую всех!

Для вывода в карточке товара веса использую такой код

```
<div class="weight">
<?php echo round($product['weight'], 2); ?>
 <?php if ($product['weight_class_id']==2) {?>
 <?php echo " гр"; ?>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php if ($product['weight_class_id']==1) {?>
 <?php echo ' кг'; ?>
 <?php } ?>    
</div>
```

В админке в единицах веса добавил литры, как отформатировать код, чтобы в зависимости от выбора выводились и литры?

Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 1):

Это решение, если следовать "стилю" кода, который приведен выше. В этом случае, если $product['weight_class_id'] равен 3, то выводятся литры.

```
<div class="weight">
  <?php echo round($product['weight'], 2); ?>
  <?php if ($product['weight_class_id']==2) {?>
  <?php echo " гр"; ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($product['weight_class_id']==1) {?>
  <?php echo ' кг'; ?>
  <?php } ?>    
  <?php if ($product['weight_class_id']==3) {?>
  <?php echo ' л'; ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

Но признаться, это не лучшее решение. 
В зависимости от архитектуры, я бы, вероятно, добавил свойство к массиву $product["placeholder"] = 'гр' || 'кг' || 'л' и т.д., и подставлял бы уже его, а не "weight_class_id".

Тогда код бы выглядел так:

```
<div class="weight">
   <?php 
      echo round($product['weight'], 2) . ' ' . $product["placeholder"];          
   ?>
</div>
```

Если же работать с текущей архитектурой объекта, то я все равно делал бы это не через "if", а через конструкцию [switch](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php)

```
<?php
   echo round($product['weight'], 2);
   switch ($product['weight_class_id']) {
      case 1:
         echo " гр";
         break;
      case 2:
         echo " кг";
         break;
      case 3:
         echo " л";
         break;
      default:
         echo "единицы измерения не указаны";
    }

?>
```

Comment: В том то и дело, я так и поступил, добавил `<?php if ($product['weight_class_id']==3) `  но единица Литр не выводится, пусто. если использовать конструкцию switch , литры тоже не выводятся, выводится default

Comment: А как вы задаете значение для $product['weight_class_id'] ? Ему где-нибудь  присваивается значение равное 3?

Comment: Я так понимаю, $product['weight_class_id'] , ему присваивается, когда в админ части добавляешь. Было две еденицы веса кг и гр, добавилась третья - Л, разве нет?

Comment: Все, разобрался.  если следовать "стилю" кода, который приведен, то надо присваивать значение равно 7, $weight_class_id == 7, в чем можно убедиться глянув на токен в адресной строке.

Answer (score 0):

Для OpenCart 3 сделал так:

```
{% if weight_class_id == 1 %}л.{% elseif weight_class_id == 2 %}г.{% else %}кг.{% endif %}
```